# @Inject property showing as "unknown property" on JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

I am working on a Java EE project. I have a bean which is using @Inject on another bean. For example:

```
@Inject
VendorBean vendor;
```

The bean with this code inside is called poGeneratorBean. In my JSF I am trying to call poGeneratorBean.vendor.x, however it is saying that vendor is an unknown property. I have tried putting public in front of "VendorBean vendor;" but that didn't do anything either.

Sorry this question might be a little vague, I am trying my best to explain the situation. Basically I am trying to display properties from VendorBean, using the poGeneratorBean via the @Inject, onto my JSF page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a public getter for it, conform the [Javabeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html).

```
public VendorBean getVendor() {
    return vendor;
}
```

[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) namely works as per the Javabeans specification.

Comment: Wow, sorry for such a silly question! Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @BalusC Hello. I have the exact same problem. I'm using `@Inject`. But ALL getters are written and  are public. Still I get the same error. All my getters follow JavaBean  notation. What else should I consider to solve this issue ?

Comment: @KurtMiller If you still get the same error even though when you're 100% sure that the code is correct, then chances are very big that you aren't running the code you think you're running. Clean, rebuild, inspect WAR, etc.